# Setting javascript tabs

Tags: javascript, html

Good day. I write tabs on javascript. The idea behind these tabs is soundly common, but there is a slight difference from the standard ones. When I click on the "+" button, all tabs should be closed and only the one that was clicked should open. Everything works well, but I just can not implement the closing of the tab on the second click of the button

[image]

HTML

```
        <div class="faq__tab">
          <div class="faq__tab__question">
            Какие вложения необходимы для того, чтобы<br>
            начать торговать на Wildberries?
            <div class="faq__tab__qeustion-btn" data-tab='0'></div>
          </div>
          <div class="faq__tab__answer">
            <span class="tab-answer">
              Какие вложения необходимы для того, чтобы<br>
              начать торговать на Wildberries?
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
```

JS

```
const tabButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.faq__tab__qeustion-btn');
const tabAnswers = document.querySelectorAll('.faq__tab__answer');
const answer = document.querySelectorAll('tab-answer');

let tabClicked = false;

tabButtons.forEach((btn, index) => {

  btn.addEventListener('click', selectTab)

})

function selectTab() {

  tabButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.classList.remove('faq__tab__qeustion-btn--active');
  });

  tabAnswers.forEach(answer => {
    answer.classList.remove('faq__tab__answer--active');
  })

  this.classList.add('faq__tab__qeustion-btn--active');
  tabAnswers[this.getAttribute('data-tab')].classList.add('faq__tab__answer--active');

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the original state of the tab in a variable, then [toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) the opposite of the original state on the clicked tab after closing all.

```
tabButtons.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', selectTab)
});
function selectTab() {
    const tab = tabAnswers[this.dataset.tab];
    const makeThisActive = !tab.classList.contains('faq__tab__answer--active');
    tabButtons.forEach(button => {
        button.classList.remove('faq__tab__qeustion-btn--active');
    });
    tabAnswers.forEach(answer => {
        answer.classList.remove('faq__tab__answer--active');
    })
    this.classList.toggle('faq__tab__qeustion-btn--active', makeThisActive);
    tab.classList.toggle('faq__tab__answer--active', makeThisActive);
}
```

I'd also recommend fixing the `qeustion` - looks like a typo, and typos are frequent causes of bugs in programming.

Comment: Thank you very much, thanks to you I figured it out!